# How to index plain text files (other than *.txt)

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

I want to index all source code of my application. The code library contains multiple extensions - .html, .js, .py, .php, .json etc. I wish to index them all. However my first try to index them like so

```
bin/post -c gettingstarted ~/Projects/myapp/
```

was not successful. I see that it indexed only *.txt files.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. For some reason, `Apache Solr` does not index .js, .py and some other files by default. So, to force it index them, you have to do it like this:

```
bin/post -c gettingstarted -filetypes js,py ~/Projects/myapp/
```